# Full Calendar feed with JSON ( Getting data from a restfull webservice )

Tags: json, ajax, jsp, fullcalendar

i have this situation.
I need to use fullCalendar 3.8 to show some reservations.
I have the back end that give me the data in JSON format ( i have about 10 fields ).
In front-end i have a JSP that inlcude fullcalendar, moment and jquery. I need to populate my FullCalendar.
Example the Json that i have is in this form:

```
[
{
    "idReservation": 21,
    "idUser": 2,
    "idSale": 1,
    "timeStart": 1513839600000,
    "timeEnd": 1513850400000
},
{
    "idReservation": 22,
    "idUser": 1,
    "idSale": 1,
    "timeStart": 1513854000000,
    "timeEnd": 1513857600000
} ]
```

Someone can tell me where can i start to study, make test in the way to feed my calendar with this data ?
i have try to read a lot of articles but cause i am not a Front-End developer i am loosing around :)

The Javascript code that i created is this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var value=2;
  returnReservationsCalendar(value);
  });

  function returnReservationsCalendar(value){
        var serviceEndpoint = 
    'http://localhost:8080/sale/'+value+'/reservations';
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url: serviceEndpoint,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({                       
                    header: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                        },          
                    defaultDate: '2014-11-13',
                    editable: true,
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

                events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                var events = [];
                $.each(result, function (index) {
                     events.push({
                      "title": "Event " + index,
                      "start": result[index].timeStart.toISOString(),
                      "end": result[index].timeEnd.toISOString(),
                     });
                });
                callback(events);               
                }
             });
            },
    error: function () { alert('Failed!'); }
});
}
```

At the JSP i have only this code:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

The problem is that i have the json response from ajax but i dont understand where i am making the mistake about populating the calendar with the data from json.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/ would seem a good place to start studying, don't you think? And https://fullcalendar.io/ has links to working examples. One tip: your JSON is not in a format which is compatible with fullCalendar, so you should consider altering it, if possible, to match the required structure (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/). If that's not possible for any reason, you can transform it by handling the eventDataTransform callback https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/ . Beyond that, your question is too vague to answer properly.

Comment: Also, you mention you have some code in your JSP - why not show it? Show us what exact problem you're having and describe it. I'm pretty sure it's going to be this data format which is giving you trouble, but since you mention you're not normally a front-end developer it would make sense to show us the rest of your calendar code in case you've made some other mistakes. We can't fix what we can't see.

Comment: Hi ADyson, i am managing everything with Jquery and Ajax call. On the jsp i have only ine div where i should put the calendar. 

Thanks for the tips of the first message. I need just a starting point here to start studying and doing some examples because i was loosing around :) thanks a lot

Comment: A vague description is no use to me. If the calendar isn't working, paste your code and also any errors coming from your browser's console and network tools. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/ is also your friend, as well as the links I posted above. And do you understand my point about your data format?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Your code is back to front. The ajax call should be _within_ the "events" function of your calendar. That way it can refresh from the server whenever the user moves to a new time period on the calendar (your server code should be only returning events which occur within or overlap into the `start` and `end` dates supplied in the events callback function). That's not the source of your problem, just a design tip.

Answer (score -1):

You should be seeing errors in your browser's console similar to this (this is as per Google Chrome, others may vary slightly):

> Uncaught TypeError: result[index].timeStart.toISOString is not a
>   function

Simply this is because `timeStart` is a string from your JSON, not a momentJS or Date object.

You need to pass it through the momentJS constructor before this will work:

```
events.push({
  "title": "Event " + index,
  "start": moment(result[index].timeStart).toISOString(),
  "end": moment(result[index].timeEnd).toISOString(),
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/166/ for a working demo (using a static event list instead of ajax, but it demonstrates the part which is relevant to this answer.

Comment: it is strange cause at the console i didn't have any error about the date. But the code that i created and modify how you say it doesn't visualize nothing. On succes of call of ajax i need to have this date and go to populate the calendar. The problem is that it is not populating the calendar in no way.

Comment: Hmm, well here it is actually using a JSON endpoint: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/167/ . Obviously it's not your real one because I don't have access to it, but you can see how the code ought to be written. So if that's how you've done it then the only conclusion I can come to is that  your server code isn't working, or isn't returning what you expect. I can't see that obviously, and I certainly can't run it to test it, but you can debug it, and also watch via your browser's network tab to see if it loads and what the response is.

Comment: Hi Adyson, i am executing the same function that you send me and it doesn't function cause when i do debug after this point:  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({      it go at the end of the function and doesn't execute nothing.
I dont have any error even in the console.

Comment: that's because that `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ ` is just one method containing a set of options you give to fullcalendar. The "events" callback function is executed later by fullCalendar once it's rendered the main calendar and goes off to fetch the events. You should see an ajax call being made if you look in your browser's Network tools. Watch the example in my JSFiddle to see what I mean. Obviously you say you execute exactly the same code in your version but without seeing it I can't tell. My version works as you can see. You just need to swap the example URL with yours.